# Quotes should look different from spoilers

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, spoilers, blockquote

Spoilers are usually not quotes. But currently spoilers (after clicking) look exactly like blockquotes. So the reader has to memorize which paragraphs he clicked (spoilers), and which were already visible (quotes). Such memorization is distracting and the need for it can be avoided.

Compare (after clicking on the spoiler):

> This is a spoiler.

vs

> This is a quote.

A different hue with same lightness would be not so colorblind-friendly, but would be a great start. Maybe **additionally** a big symbolic quotation mark like on other websites would be appropriate.

**Edit**: This improvement should be implemented directly on the SE website. It shouldn't be reserved to users who have the time, tech skills, and access rights to install userstyles.

In the wake of this improvement, it could also be made clearer that [spoilers are clickable and not only hoverable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337979/quotes-should-look-different-from-spoilers?noredirect=1#comment1125080_337979).

Comment: It would be cool if we could set personal rendering preferences in our profiles.  For example, I usually don't care about spoilers spoiling stuff, so it'd be cool if I could just set a rendering option that suppressed the hiding.

Comment: This isn't much of an issue on the mobile site or apps.

Comment: This is something that can be done via user styles, and IMO this should be done by user styles.

Comment: @Nat I have a CSS-based solution for that as well in my answer.

Comment: Huh, today I learned that I can click on a spoiler and it stays visible.  Up till now I was always hovering over them.

Comment: What's your beef with lightness? ;)

Comment: Dang it, OP, now I know Harry was a wizard :(

Comment: Dupe of [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes), particularly [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345063/241919).

Answer (score 18):

The spoiler feels very 1998. It reminds me of the `<marquee>` tag, but I like it.

I think the current spoiler-guard

> If you saw this text before you knew this was supposed to be hidden I haven't done my job.

isn't clear what it is. At first it just looks like the poster made a mistake and left a blank box.

> 

The spoiler shouldn't reveal what is under it on flyover. It should require a click.

It should be clearer that it hides some information from the UI at a first glance. Gray can would work well against black text. [Stripes](http://www.stripegenerator.com/) help indicate it is a type of "scratchable screen" -

[image: spoiler guard]

Don't look now, but CSS 3 supports candy stripes

```
<style>
.spoiler {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(
  135deg,
  #fff,
  #fff 15px,
  #eee 15px,
  #eee 20px
  );
}
</style>
<p class="spoiler">
    some spoiler text
</p>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, on mobile it says "click to show spoiler" and you have to press the quote box. On the desktop version of mobile it's just a blank box though whose text is invisible until you tap it

Comment: @Medix2 or flyover

Comment: Re *"The spoiler feels very 1998"*: And blinking ads?

Comment: @PeterMortensen 1999

Answer (score 7):

As @muru notes in the comments, this can be done by user styles; small snippets of CSS which can be added to a webpage with an extension like [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus#releases). The first block below adds a quotation mark to blockquotes; the second one changes the background of a spoiler block to the 'scratchable screen surface' from [@bobobobo's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337984/295232).

```css
blockquote:not([class=""]):not(.spoiler) > p::before {
    content: "“";
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

blockquote[class=""], blockquote.spoiler {
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(
        135deg,
        #fff,
        #fff 15px,
        #eee 15px,
        #eee 20px
    );
    border-left: 2px solid #bbb;
}
```

Results (after I clicked on the spoiler in your question):

[image]

Probably somebody with more CSS skills / better ideas than me can make something nicer. In particular, I'd like the quotation marks to become larger without increasing the height of single-line blockquotes (which is what happens if you add e.g. `font-size: 2em`).

The main trick here is that a `blockquote` element for a quote has no `class` attribute at all, while a spoiler has `class="spoiler"` before clicking and `class=""` after; that's the only CSS-accessible way to distinguish them.

There are other browser extensions which can do CSS enhancements; I'd avoid Stylish for reasons mentioned [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/199925/71850).

---

If you need a CSS-based solution to disable spoilers altogether, as mentioned by @Nat in the comments, you'd need something like this:

```css
.spoiler:not(:hover) > * {
    opacity: 1;
}
.spoiler:not(:hover) {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This improvement should be implemented directly on the SE website. It shouldn't be reserved to users who have the time, tech skills, and access rights to install userstyles. I guess your suggestions are meant as a draft for an SE-wide change.

Comment: Many improvements to the network have started out as userscripts/userstyles.

Answer (score 5):

It *looks* like a new CSS update just implemented this feature request:

[image]

Blockquotes don't have the yellow background anymore, and the background for spoilers has been changed to a light gray.

Comment: [Original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/345161) on it.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't solve the issue. Click on the spoiler (this unhides the text) - it will look the same as a quote.

Comment: @root Not so? Spoilers that are revealed should still have a grey background.

Comment: @Catija The gray background still exists if you mouse over it, but when you *click* it, it disappears.