# Clicking on a spoiler incorrectly removes the gray background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers

As of the [recent CSS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/345161) to quote markup and spoilers, quotes no longer have a colored background, while spoilers do:

> This is a quote.

and

> This is a spoiler.

When the spoiler is merely hovered over, the gray background remains in place, but when the spoiler is clicked (to continuously show the text without hovering), the gray background will disappear and it will look exactly like a quote. (This is more easily reproducible on desktop browsers; on mobile browsers, a touchscreen tap may just emulate a mouseover.)

While I wasn't sure whether this is an intentional feature or a bug, a CM [said the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337979/quotes-should-look-different-from-spoilers#comment1155908_344846) in response to a user complaint about this behavior:

> Not so? Spoilers that are revealed should still have a grey background.

Therefore, it's a bug, and should be fixed.

Comment: A quick note to avoid confusion...it seems this question was accidentally [double posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344926/clicking-on-a-spoiler-should-not-remove-the-gray-background) for some reason. If you were looking at the other question and wondering that you saw it deleted, you were probably looking at that.

Comment: I can confirm that clicking converts the appearance of a spoiler to that of a block quote, on a desktop PC. Clicking again reverts it to a spoiler. I had not noticed this behaviour for the previous styling, and of course, I can't check if that was how it behaved before – I had thought it was just a hovering thing.

Comment: Looking at the CSS it looks like the way they now implement "click to show spoiler" is to simply remove the spoiler class. It looks like a deliberate code simplification that's fine for ordinary users simply reading content, who don't care if it *was previously* a spoiler, **but** a potential nuisance for mods, highly-active users and askers who need to know if something *was* a spoiler to judge if it should be edited. I'd say to who did this: nice idea, but we do need a visual cue so people don't scroll up and mistakenly think "Wait, that should have been in a spoiler block".

Answer (score 5):

This has been completed as part of new [post formatting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting).